# How to force Apache to release filelocks?

Tags: apache, file-locking, filelock

I'm not sure if I am using the correct terminology here, but after rendering a file on localhost, on a local machine, I am unable to save the file after editing - the file is locked and noted as being opened by another program. This turns out to be httpd.exe

Is there a directive I can use to force file release or what is occurring here?
Using Apache 2.2

Comment: Multi-posted to SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/890618/

Comment: Yes indeed I did but as I commented there, in that I needed to register a separate account I assumed that posts were not visible across the boundary. I notice now that Stackexchange notifications pop up relating to both resources. So apologies if this was not appropriate.